# asp.net connectionstring

Tags: asp.net

i have working ASP.net 2.0 with back end MS SQL-2008(windows authentication), in that i have use OLEDB provider for connection string but it shows the error

**Cannot open database "PowerNet" requested by the login. The login failed.**

if any ideas

Comment: How did you configure authentication in your SQL Server? Which Logins did you create? Which Users did you create in the database?

Comment: And also give some votes... its seams that you do not wish to give any credits to the people that help you.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your connection string settings don't provide correct login information.

Comment: Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=.\sqlexp;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=PowerNet            //this is my connection string

Answer (score 0):

Have you switched on impersonation

```
  <!-- Web.config file. -->
  <identity impersonate="true"/>
```

and IIS integrated windows security for your web application?

[image]

Otherwise the application will attempt to connect to your SQL Server using the identity which is running the IIS Application Pool in which your application is running. This identity probably doesn't have the necessary privileges to the database.

Comment: it's work with windows auth.. i think we don't want to mention the username password here

Comment: if i run the application with F5 it's working if i use http://localhost/log/plan.aspx like this then the error will came

Comment: and your browser (IE) is configured to provide user authentication information?

Comment: Does it work if you use the actual machine name instead of localhost?

Comment: Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=christ\sqlexp;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=PowerNet    ---- i have tried like this but it not wrkng